# extend scope of pass by ref object for std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

To demonstrate the problem, let me present a short code -

```
void someMethod() {

  // CustomType obj;
  const auto obj = getCustomTypeObj();

  std::thread([](customType &obj) {
    // some delay
    obj.doSomething();
    obj.close();
    // can now be destructed
  }).detach();

  // similarly for std::async
  std::async(std::launch::async, [](customType &obj){
    obj.doSomething();
    obj.close();
  }

  // there might not be any use of obj here

  // should not be destructed here because std::thread might not get it.

}
```

In above code, an `CustomType` type object is constructed for which copy constructor is deleted. So I must pass it by reference everywhere, or create it from scratch in relevant scope. However for 1 scenario I'm currently dealing with, it is not quite possible to create it in relevant scope which is inside `std::thread`'s execution method.

What I'm afraid of is `obj` might be destructed before `std::thread` even completes its job and then I've no idea what's going to happen. So how should I solve this problem of extending it's scope to std::thread's lambda.

Comment: Use a smart pointer to control object lifetime

Comment: @Slava sorry I didn't mentioned it earlier but I'm not exactly declaring the object as such, I'm getting it from a method. So I'm not sure how will I use smart pointer here. I've made the edit.

Comment: In this case pass it by value, so lambda will get a copy that will live until it terminates, don't use reference

Comment: If what you say is true, then you need to utilize a barrier so main doesn't return before your threads do.

Comment: @Slava there is no copy constructor as I've stated, how to pass by value :/

Comment: Btw you use `std::thread` incorrectly - you must call join before it is destructed. If you make it named variable then your problem is gone

Comment: @hg_git if there is no copy nor move constructor then you cannot return it from a method.

Comment: @Slava only copy is deleted, move is still there. Will pass by value fall back to move?

Comment: @hg_git if you use `std::move()` explicitly then yes it would be moved

Comment: @AnonMail you're right but how to do that. Also since `main()` is a special method, I've edited the question to use `someMethod` so it's more generic and I'm detaching now.

Comment: @Slava I made a mistake to not call `detach` there because I'm trying to relate to `std::async` here too. I've made the edit.

Comment: Sounds like you need to a `std::shared_ptr`.  You should be able to use something like `auto obj = std::make_shared<type_of_obj>(getCustomTypeObj());`.

Comment: yes @NathanOliver that sounds right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Btw your code is incorrect, you do not pass your object, so your code should be instead:

```
  auto obj = getCustomTypeObj();

  std::thread([](customType &obj) {
    // some delay
    obj.doSomething();
    obj.close();
    // can now be destructed
  }, std::ref( obj ) ).detach();
```

To avoid issue with object lifetime pass your object to the lambda or function by value and move your object there:

```
  auto obj = getCustomTypeObj();

  std::thread([](customType arg) { // note by value, not reference
    // some delay
    arg.doSomething();
    arg.close();
    // arg will be destroyed here
  }, std::move( obj ) ).detach(); // object moved
```

now lambda or function owns that object and it will be destroyed at the end of the function. Here is the [live example](http://ideone.com/I1xoQ3), I just used `std::unique_ptr` there instead of `customType` as type that has copying disabled to validate that moving works.

Comment: I didn't think of shared_ptr too, if you could add a line about having share_ptr as another option, that'll be great :D

Comment: I do not think you need `std::shared_ptr` in this case, if your function can return that object then it could and should be moved into thread function. If your function would return `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` then solution would be obvious.